Is there a way to add lines across subplots in Python
I have a simple plot, to which I've added lines as below:
mid = d[d.Position==0].Price.mean()
b_a = d[(d.Position==0) & (d.Side == 0)].Price.values
b_b = d[(d.Position==0) & (d.Side == 1)].Price.values

f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_color_codes('muted')

sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==0], x = 'Price', y = 'Size', color = 'b',  native_scale=True)
sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==1], x = 'Price', y = 'Size', color = 'r',  native_scale=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.0001))
plt.axvline(x=mid, color = 'b', lw = 1.5)
plt.axvline(x=b_a, color = 'k', lw = 1, ls='--')
plt.axvline(x=b_b, color = 'k', lw = 1, ls='--')


Data looks like this:
d
    Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
9   9   0   1   0.7289  -16
8   8   0   1   0.729   -427
7   7   0   1   0.7291  -267
6   6   0   1   0.7292  -15
5   5   0   1   0.7293  -16
4   4   0   1   0.7294  -16
3   3   0   1   0.7295  -426
2   2   0   1   0.7296  -8
1   1   0   1   0.7297  -14
0   0   0   1   0.7298  -37
10  0   0   0   0.7299  6
11  1   0   0   0.73    34
12  2   0   0   0.7301  7
13  3   0   0   0.7302  9
14  4   0   0   0.7303  16
15  5   0   0   0.7304  15
16  6   0   0   0.7305  429
17  7   0   0   0.7306  16
18  8   0   0   0.7307  265
19  9   0   0   0.7308  18

I'd like to plot a number of this sequentially using matplotlib's subplots method like this (here, x and y are just a collection of values from prior d dataframes assembled for plotting):
cnt = 5

f, ax = plt.subplots(cnt, 1, sharex=True)
sns.set_color_codes('muted')

for i in range(cnt):
    sns.barplot(x = x.iloc[i, 10:].values, y = y.iloc[i, 10:].values, color = 'b',  native_scale=True, ax = ax[i])
    sns.barplot(x = x.iloc[i, :10].values, y = y.iloc[i, 10:].values, color = 'r',  native_scale=True, ax = ax[i])
    ax[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.0001))
    


Is there a way to create connecting lines across subplots? Like this crude version below?


It can definitely be done, but it's not trivial and perhaps not a great idea? What do the lines represent? Should they really run diagonally across each chart, or would that be confusing? You could add the lines in the appropriate location for each chart quite simply. Connecting them between charts would be doable as well, but getting the lines to run from some spot on the x-axis of each chart to another spot on the x-axis of the next chart seems odd.

ConnectionPatch will draw a line between points in different axes https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch

@Grismar, absent specifics of the data (which arent private but require context) theyre reference points for each plot (ie, think 25/median/75th percentile).  I want to visualize how these change over time in an immediately obvious way

I don't understand why you would want the lines to overrun the subplot though.  Or be slanted.  If I were doing this, I'd just add the vertical lines to each subplot individually.

@JodyKlymak, it's fine that you don't understand it, not at all relevant here

This is a bit hacky but it should work:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1).clf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 1, num=1, sharex=True)

# plot your data
x = np.arange(100)
for a in ax:
    plt.sca(a)
    plt.plot(x, np.random.randn(100))

# add the lines
values = [20, 20, 30, 30, 20]
for i in range(5):
    plt.sca(ax[i])
    ylim = plt.ylim()
    v = values[i]
    v_ = v if i==0 else values[i-1]
    plt.plot([v, v_], ylim, 'g')
    plt.plot([v-10, v_-10], ylim, 'r--')
    plt.plot([v+10, v_+10], ylim, 'r--')
    plt.ylim(*ylim)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.show()



How so? It did produce that graph on my machine...

It was still missing the imports, but I suppose I grabbed an early edit - the current one works as advertised.

Thanks bud...will take a closer look tmrw and report back after applying

Champ, output is as desired (albeit a lil wonky).  Thanks man!

Solution given @Grismar's answer:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mid = x.iloc[:,9:11].values.mean(axis=1)
b_a = x.iloc[:,9].values
b_b = x.iloc[:,10].values


cnt = 5

f, ax = plt.subplots(cnt, 1, sharex=True)
sns.set_color_codes('muted')

for i in range(cnt):
    sns.barplot(x = x.iloc[i, 10:].values, y = y.iloc[i, 10:].values, color = 'b',  native_scale=True, ax = ax[i])
    sns.barplot(x = x.iloc[i, :10].values, y = y.iloc[i, 10:].values, color = 'r',  native_scale=True, ax = ax[i])
    ax[i].set_xlim([x_min-.0001,x_max+.0001])
    ax[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.0001))
    
    plt.sca(ax[i])
    ylim = plt.ylim()
    m = mid[i]
    a = b_a[i]
    b = b_b[i]
    m_ = m if i==0 else mid[i-1]
    b_ = b if i==0 else b_b[i-1]
    a_ = a if i==0 else b_a[i-1]
    
    plt.plot([m, m_], ylim, 'g')
    plt.plot([b, b_], ylim, 'r--')
    plt.plot([a, a_], ylim, 'r--')
    plt.ylim(*ylim)
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)    


